# Ruby on Rails print and download pdf using pdf middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I have installed PDFkit in my rails-project, all works great, but I didn't find any way to print and download generated pdf. I believe that there is anybody who had the same issues as me.

Comment: As far as downloading, just output a link tot he PDF. As far as printing, do you want to print it from the server, or from the client?

Comment: from the client, I guess?